# upper floors / top floors

Tags: idiomatic-language

> They are searching the upper/top floors of the building.

Do "upper floors" and "top floors" mean the same thing? If yes, is one of them more commonly used than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Denotatively, “upper floors” and “top floors” mean any floor above the ground floor.

In use, however, “top floors” tends to be reserved for those upper floors that are topmost.

If you have a house with a basement, a ground floor, and two floors above the ground floor, then, in the U.S., you would typically call the story immediately above the ground floor the “second story” and the topmost the “top story” or “third story” or, in some cases, the “attic.”

In a skyscraper with 100 stories, it would be very odd, quite unidiomatic, to refer to the two stories immediately above the ground floor as “top floors.” They would likely be called “lower floors” with the implicit understanding that they were above the ground floor, but had many stories above them.

In short, in the U.S., “top floors” (note the plural) typically refers to the floors that are toward the top of a building with more than three or four stories, whereas “upper floors” refers to all those above the ground floor.

Example

> The first two floors are devoted to retail stores and restaurants, with each upper floor devoted to offices or apartments, except that the each of the top three floors is reserved for apartments are urban mansions, each complete with garden space and a private swimming pool.

Here “upper floor” means floors above the second story but below the three topmost stories.